# I had created apk 2 days ago and it was working properly. But when i try today i am getting errors. Even i didn't change anything in my code today

Tags: react-native, android-studio

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:mergeDebugAssets'.

> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Could not resolve com.facebook.react:react-native:+.
> Required by:
> project :app
> project :app > project :react-native-push-notification
> project :app > project :@react-native-async-storage_async-storage
> project :app > project :@react-native-community_datetimepicker
> project :app > project :@react-native-community_masked-view
> project :app > project :@react-native-firebase_app
> project :app > project :@react-native-firebase_messaging
> project :app > project :react-native-gesture-handler
> project :app > project :react-native-image-crop-picker
> project :app > project :react-native-safe-area-context
> project :app > project :react-native-screens
> > Failed to list versions for com.facebook.react:react-native.
> > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/react/react-native/maven-metadata.xml.
> > Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/react/react-native/maven-metadata.xml'.
> > Read timed out

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 54s

I am not getting any proper solutions from anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Try method 01:
Clear gradle file and install the app ,now again install the app
Method  02:
Open android emulator wipe your data
Run again
Method 03:
Backup ur npm folder and remove npm from specific dir, and use npm install it will automatically  download all package and run